# How can I read specific column values by apache poi methods with specific condition applied in other column value?

Tags: java, iterator, apache-poi, java-io

I want to read data of a particular column applying some condition to other columns like I have mentioned bellow.
Here is what I have tried to do.

[image]

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1){
            if(cell.getNumericCellValue()==52){
                System.out.println(/* print name from 0th column deep should be printed*/);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use nextRow.getCell(cellnum)  directly instead of iterator. Please check Apache POI docs here https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nextRow.getCell(cellnum) directly instead of iterator. Please check Apache POI docs here poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

    Cell1 = nextRow.getCell(1);
    Cell0 = nextRow.getCell(0);
    if(cell1.getNumericCellValue()==52){

       System.out.println(cell0.getStringCellValue());
    }

}
```